# Ring of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, with $n$ square-free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring of order $n$ and suppose $n$ has no square in its prime decomposition. How do I see that $R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$?

I bet that the map $\Bbb Z  \to R, \, 1\mapsto 1_R$ descends to an iso $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \to R$ but I don't see how $n$ having no squares implies the desired descent.

Comment: Do you see that it is enough to show that the characteristic must be $n$?

Comment: The characteristic is the integer $k$ with such that the kernel of the map above is $k \Bbb Z$. So if the char is $n$, the map descends to $\Bbb Z/n$. The map is also injective and therefore surjective (finiteness) and therefore an iso. That's why it suffices to show that the characteristic in $n$ right?

Comment: That is one way to think about it. Or it is the size of the subgroup generated by $1$, which you are trying to show is the entire group.

Comment: Now, if $p$ is some prime which divides $n$ but not the characteristic, what happens if you consider an element of order $p$ in the abelian group underlying the ring?

Comment: you also need to verify that this map preserves the multiplicative structure as well

Comment: Dumb question: Why is there an element of order $p$ in the abelian group $(R,+)$? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: By Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: So if $p$ divides $n$ we get some $x\in R$ with $px=0$. And if $p$ does *not* divide the char of $R$, then $p$ is nonzero is $R$ (is that true?). So $x=0$.

Comment: What you need to use here is that because the order is $p$ and $p$ does not divide $n$, you have $nx\neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, @TobiasKildetoft. What is the logic of the argument we're trying to do? Are we trying to show that any prime dividing $n$ divides the characteristic of $R$? Does this imply $\operatorname{char} R=n$?

Comment: Yes, if the characteristic is divisible by all primes dividing $n$ then it equals $n$ since $n$ is squarefree.

Comment: Ah, OK, and we get that $\operatorname{char} R=n$ because we always have $\operatorname{char} R\leq n$ and if all primes dividing $n$ divide char, then the reverse inequality is true too?

Comment: (sorry for asking all these silly questions)

Comment: Another way to prove is to show that every ring of order $n$ with cyclic abelian group is actually $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Then your claim follows from [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67143).

Comment: For the claim in my previous comment, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113505).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $n$ is square-free, then the additive group of $R$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups of prime order and its characteristic is then equal to $n$.

---

If $n$ is not square free, say $p^k\mid n$ and $p^{k+1}\nmid n$, with $p$ a prime and $k>1$, then there are two nonisomorphic rings with order $n$, namely
$$
\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^{k-1}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $m=n/p^k$.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the problem to the following lemma

> If $p \mid n$, $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}  \to R / pR$ is well-defined an isomorphism

Since all of the ideals $pR$ and $qR$ are coprime, the Chinese remainder theorem asserts

$$ R = R / nR \cong \prod_{p \mid n} \mathbb{Z}  / p \mathbb{Z}  \cong \mathbb{Z}  / n \mathbb{Z}  $$

If $n$ is not squarefree, there are examples where $\mathbb{Z}  / p^2 \mathbb{Z}  \to R / p^2 R $ is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

We can smuggle the core idea of Cayley's theorem from group theory into ring theory and show that $R$ embeds in the ring of endomorphisms of $R$ as an additive group:

$$ \phi : R \to \text{End}(R,+) \quad \text{as} \quad \phi(r) = [s \mapsto rs] \text.$$

Now, $(R, +)$ is cyclic because $n = |R|$ is **squarefree**, so $\text{End}(R, +) \cong \text{End}(C_n)$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.

And $\text{End}(C_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. (If $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $g \mapsto n \cdot g = \sum_{i = 1}^n g$ is an endomorphism of any abelian group; in the case of $C_n$, the image of the generator determines the endomorphism.)

So $R$ embeds in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The embedding must be an isomorphism since the two rings in question are finite.